# 2-way binding issue in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, angularjs

I am getting my hands dirty on HTML + AngularJs. I am stuck on a strange problem.
I create table,tr,td using ng-repeat, iterating over json data and fill value in input type text using Json object property "name". Now when I type in input box, ng-model get updated ,but if I try it with a prefilled value in JSON property OR I try to fill JSON property dynamically ,it doesn't update.

```
    <table style="border:1px solid black" ng-repeat="node in tableJson" id="tableId">
        <tr  style="border:1px solid black" ng-repeat=" rowNode in node">
            <td style="border:1px solid black" ng-repeat="columnNode in rowNode">

            <div ng-repeat="obj in columnNode">


                {{obj.name}}
                <span ng-click="addRow($parent.$index,$index);">add row</span></br>
                <span ng-click="addColumn();">add column</span></br>
                <span ng-click="hideMeShowNext();">hide me</span>
                id: {{$parent.$parent.$index}}_{{$parent.$index}}_{{$index}}
                <input type="text" ng-model="obj.name">{{obj.name}}

                <table style="border:1px solid black" ng-repeat="node in obj.newTable" id="tableId">
                    <tr  style="border:1px solid black" ng-repeat=" rowNode in node">
                        <td style="border:1px solid black" ng-repeat="columnNode in rowNode">

                            <div ng-repeat="obj in columnNode">
                                <span ng-click="addRow($parent.$index,$index);">add row</span></br>
                                <span ng-click="addColumn();">add column</span></br>
                                <span ng-click="hideMeShowNext();">hide me</span>
                                id: {{$parent.$parent.$index}}_{{$parent.$index}}_{{$index}}
                                <input type="text" ng-model="obj.name">{{obj.name}}
                            </div>  
                        </td>
                    </tr>   
                </table>    

            </div>  
            </td>
        </tr>   
</table>
```

This is HTML part.

```
    $scope.tableJson = [
  {
    "rowNode": [
      {
        "columnNode": [
          {
            "name":"bababab"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

This is predefined JSON.

```
$scope.addRow =function(parentIndex,index){
//add a tr to the container table


alert(parentIndex + "--"+index);

var objToPush = [
  {
    "rowNode": [
      {
        "columnNode": [
          {
            "name": ""
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
$scope.tableJson[0]["rowNode"][parentIndex]["columnNode"][index]["name"]="justFilled";
$scope.tableJson[0]["rowNode"][parentIndex]["columnNode"][index]["newTable"] = objToPush;

$scope.$apply();
}
```

addRow is the function I am calling.

What am I doing wrong?>

Comment: best suggestion might be to start with a simple test case that doesn't include so much nesting, and just push an empty object into the array for the rows. Once you figure the simple case out, apply what you learn to the deeper nested object

Comment: $scope.$apply is unnecessary there ( but removing it won't fix your problem ). I believe you should to as charlietfl says : begin with a smaller nested structure and augment it little by little, you will find the mistake

Comment: @charlietfl I tried, printed {{obj}} on page.It seems it get updated but ng-repeat don't update. I am working on it.Will update as soon a I got an answer.